# ¿Como puedo hacer la parte de las ecuaciones de segundo grado incompletas?

Tags: java

Lo que pone en el Ejercicio :

```
/*
    1. Realiza un programa capaz de calcular ecuaciones de segundo grado completa e incompletas.
    2. Deberas Intentar Controlar todas las exceciones posibles
 */
```

Ecuaciones de Segundo Grado Completa :

```
 public void ecuacion2G() {
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de a : ");
        a = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de b : ");
        b = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de c : ");
        c = teclado.nextDouble();

        if (a == 0 && b != 0) {
            System.out.println(-c / b);
        } else if ((4 * a * c) > Math.pow(b, 2)) {
            System.out.println("No tiene solución real");
        } else {
            System.out.println((-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
            System.out.println((-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
        }
    }
```

Ecuaciones de Segundo Grado Incompleta(Lo que me falta):

```
 public void ecuacion2GIncompleta() {
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de a : ");
        a = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de b : ");
        b = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de c : ");
        c = teclado.nextDouble();
        if(b==0&&c==0){
            System.out.print("La unica solucion es :"+0);
        }else if(c==0){
            
        }
    }
```

En esta parte me he quedado atascado y no se como continuar.

Parte del main:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        EcuacionSegundoGrado e = new EcuacionSegundoGrado();
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opt;
        System.out.println("1. Ecuacion de Segundo Grado Completa ");
        System.out.println("2. Ecuacion de Segundo Grado Incompleta ");
        System.out.print("Elige el tipo de ecuacion : ");
        opt = teclado.nextInt();

        if (opt == 1) {
            e.ecuacion2G();
        } else if (opt == 2) {
            e.ecuacion2GIncompleta();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Por favor mete un valor correcto del menu");
        }
    }
```

Si me pudierais explicar como podría terminar los dos modo de las ecuaciones incompleta os lo agradecería e estado buscando información e estado intentado varias manera pero nada no me sale.

Donde e estado mirando : [https://www.superprof.es/apuntes/escolar/matematicas/algebra/ecuaciones/ecuaciones-de-segundo-grado-incompletas.html#:~:text=2-,Segundo%20caso,ecuaci%C3%B3n%20de%20segundo%20grado%20incompleta](https://www.superprof.es/apuntes/escolar/matematicas/algebra/ecuaciones/ecuaciones-de-segundo-grado-incompletas.html#:%7E:text=2-,Segundo%20caso,ecuaci%C3%B3n%20de%20segundo%20grado%20incompleta)).

Resumen :

Primer caso
Cuando ambos coeficientes son iguales a cero, la ecuación de segundo grado incompleta es la siguiente:
Si    b=0     y     c=0    entonces    ax² = 0     (ecuación de segundo grado incompleta).
Para este tipo de ecuación la solución es siempre   x = 0.

Segundo caso
Cuando el coeficiente c es igual a cero, la ecuación de segundo grado incompleta es la siguiente:
Si    c=0    entonces    ax² + bx = 0     (ecuación de segundo grado incompleta).
Veamos como se extraen las soluciones:

1 Extraemos factor común x.
Extraer factor común x

2 Como tenemos un producto igualado a cero, o un factor es cero, o el otro factor es cero, o ambos son cero.

Tercer caso
Cuando el coeficiente b es igual a cero, la ecuación de segundo grado incompleta es la siguiente:
Si    b=0    entonces    ax² + c = 0     (ecuación de segundo grado incompleta).
Veamos como se extraen las soluciones:

1 Pasamos el término c al segundo miembro cambiando de signo.

Despejar a x paso mover a c

2 Pasamos el coeficiente a al segundo miembro, dividiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te ha pasado es que has visto los pasos que realizan en la página para resolver esos 2 casos y no has sabido cómo sacar factor cómun, sacar la raiz, etc usando el lenguaje de java. Sinceramente, yo tampoco, pero lo que sí sé es cómo sale finalmente el resultado, en forma de la variable **x** que utilizan. Eso es lo que nos importa a nosotros.

Ten en cuenta que antes de dar la solución y ya está, sin explicar nada, hay que exponer paso a paso cómo se llega a la misma. Eso es lo que se hace en la página. Por ello mismo, solamente nos interesa la solución final a cada uno de los casos que nos brindan, esto es, las fórmulas escritas en rojo.

Paso a ponerte el código:

```java
public void ecuacion2GIncompleta() {
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de a : ");
        a = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de b : ");
        b = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de c : ");
        c = teclado.nextDouble();
        if(b==0&&c==0){
            System.out.print("La unica solucion es :"+0);
        }else if(c==0){
            System.out.println("Primera solucion: " + 0);
            System.out.println("Segunda solucion: " + -(b/a));
        }else if( b==0){
            Integer div = -c/a;
            System.out.println("Primera solucion: + " + Math.sqrt(div));
            System.out.println("Segunda solucion: - " + Math.sqrt(div) );
        }
    }
```

Como ves, solo he modificado el método que se encarga de resolver las ecuaciones de segundo grado incompletas, el resto no lo he mirado (asumo que está correcto).

Comment: gracias me has ayudo

Comment: todo genial :) muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Parte solucionada por daenius.

```
/*
    1. Realiza un programa capaz de calcular ecuaciones de segundo grado completa e incompletas.
    2. Deberas Intentar Controlar todas las exceciones posibles
 */
package boletin;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class EcuacionSegundoGrado {

    private double a, b, c;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    public EcuacionSegundoGrado(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public EcuacionSegundoGrado() {

    }

    public void ecuacion2G() {
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de a : ");
        a = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de b : ");
        b = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de c : ");
        c = teclado.nextDouble();

        if (a == 0 && b != 0) {
            System.out.println(-c / b);
        } else if ((4 * a * c) > Math.pow(b, 2)) {
            System.out.println("No tiene solución real");
        } else {
            System.out.println((-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
            System.out.println((-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a);
        }
    }

    public void ecuacion2GIncompleta() {
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de a : ");
        a = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de b : ");
        b = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Escribe la parte de la ecuacion de c : ");
        c = teclado.nextDouble();
        if(b==0&&c==0){
            System.out.print("La unica solucion es :"+0);
        }else if(c==0){
            System.out.println("Primera solucion: " + 0);
            System.out.println("Segunda solucion: " + -(b/a));
        }else if( b==0){
            double div = -c/a;
            System.out.println("Primera solucion: + " + Math.sqrt(div));
            System.out.println("Segunda solucion: - " + Math.sqrt(div) );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EcuacionSegundoGrado e = new EcuacionSegundoGrado();
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opt;
        System.out.println("1. Ecuacion de Segundo Grado Completa ");
        System.out.println("2. Ecuacion de Segundo Grado Incompleta ");
        System.out.print("Elige el tipo de ecuacion : ");
        opt = teclado.nextInt();

        if (opt == 1) {
            e.ecuacion2G();
        } else if (opt == 2) {
            e.ecuacion2GIncompleta();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Por favor mete un valor correcto del menu");
        }
    }
}
```